# How do you reply to someone correctly in this context?

Tags: grammar

Question example: "So, you've never had a job?"

This situation seems to come up often and confuses me when I chat with it seems like you could either reply yes to disagree or agree and vice versa.

Would you say "yes" or "no" if you've never had a job?

Comment: I would say "That's correct."

Comment: Is writing something other than "yes" or "no" the only way to avoid ambiguity? In that case, I'd just clarify it by saying "No, I've never had a job." Or "No, I have had a job." Seems weird that it can go either way, though.

Comment: What does this have to do with English language and usage??

Comment: There is an old song called "Yes, we have no bananas," which is clearly intended to answer the question/remark: "What?! You have no bananas?" It does seem weird that a simple "yes" or "no" can lead to confusion, but all this really suggests is that "yes" or "no" is not always a sufficient answer.

Comment: @Lambie What doesn't it??

Comment: If you can agree or disagree, that is cultural. Not linguistic or usage or anything like that.